# Differences in QueryTables.add between VBS and Macro

Tags: vba, vbscript

I have a Macro that loads a flat file into the current sheet. It searches a subfolder for a .dat file of the same name as the active sheet and loads in the data. I want to transition this to a vbs script that will loop through all of the sheets in the workbook and import all the data. I cannot use a macro because when the workbook is open and I try to do this, excel runs out of memory. Below is the macro:

```
Sub LoadData()
Dim xStrPath As String
Dim theSheet As Worksheet
Dim xFile As String
Dim xCount As Long
Dim oneCell As Range

    answer = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to reload data? This will remove all existing data.", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Warning!")
    If answer = vbYes Then
            Set theSheet = Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
            theSheet.Rows(5 & ":" & theSheet.Rows.Count).Delete
            xStrPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            xFile = xStrPath & "\Old_Data\" & theSheet.Name & ".dat"
                With theSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" _
                  & xStrPath & "\Old_Data\" & theSheet.Name & ".dat", Destination:=theSheet.Range("A5"))
                    .Name = "a" & xCount
                    .FieldNames = True
                    .RowNumbers = False
                    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
                    .PreserveFormatting = True
                    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
                    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
                    .SavePassword = False
                    .SaveData = True
                    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
                    .RefreshPeriod = 0
                    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
                    .TextFilePlatform = xlMSDOS
                    .TextFileStartRow = 1
                    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
                    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
                    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
                    .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
                    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
                    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
                    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
                    .TextFileOtherDelimiter = ","
                    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
                    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
                    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
                End With

                For Each oneColumn In theSheet.UsedRange.Columns
                    With oneColumn
                        .ColumnWidth = 40
                    End With
                Next oneColumn
    Else
    'do nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

And below is the VBScript I tried to run:

```
    Dim xStrPath
Dim theSheet
Dim xFile
Dim xCount
Dim oneCell
Dim theFile
Dim WshShell

Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set xStrPath = WshShell.CurrentDirectory
Set theFile = GetObject(xStrPath & "\Base_Tables_Template.xlsm")

For Each theSheet In theFile

    'Set theSheet = Application.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    theSheet.Rows(5 & ":" & theSheet.Rows.Count).Delete
    xFile = xStrPath & "\Old_Data\" & theSheet.Name & ".dat"
        With theSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" _ & xStrPath & "\Old_Data\" & theSheet.Name & ".dat", Destination:=theSheet.Range("A5"))
            .Name = "a" & xCount
            .FieldNames = True
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
            .TextFilePlatform = xlMSDOS
            .TextFileStartRow = 1
            .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
            .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
            .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
            .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
            .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
            .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
            .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
            .TextFileOtherDelimiter = ","
            .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
            .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With

        For Each oneColumn In theSheet.UsedRange.Columns
            With oneColumn
                .ColumnWidth = 40
            End With
        Next oneColumn
Next theSheet
```

The VBScript is giving me an expected ')' error on line 18 char 49:

[image: Error]

This line is

```
With theSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" _ & xStrPath & "\Old_Data\" & theSheet.Name & ".dat", Destination:=theSheet.Range("A5"))
```

This should be behaving the same as the macro. Why would the code expect a parenthesis when the macro executes just fine?

Comment: Your VBA-Code had the `With theSheet.QueryTables.Add...` broken into two lines. To enable the compiler to see this as one statement, you have to put an underscore char `_` at the end of the line.  However, in your VBS-Code, you have written the statement in one line - remove the underscore

Comment: Also in VBS all of the named enumerations like xlMSDOS / xlDelimited and so on will be undefined and empty unless you either type them out as consts or supply the actual value.

Comment: VBScript only does positional parameters not named ie `Connection:="TEXT`

Comment: OK - So it seems like there are more fundamental differences between VBS and VBA that will require changes in the code. OK - I will have to reconsider the approach. Thank you.

Comment: VBScript can be pasted into VBA. VBScript is legal VBA. So you can't do this in reverse. So no constants from type library (have to type them with keyboard), no named parameters (no one uses them anyway - it is heaps of extra typing) but positional, and no diming variables as anything, just dim them.